# Toolbars items disappearing when initialized from shared NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Recently had to take up the iOS dev mantle again after being away for quite a bit and I'm getting hit my retain/strong memory issues again. Basically I have two view controllers which I am switching between using present view controller. In their viewDidLoad method, I set the toolbaritems property. Now, I didn't want to have this be written identically in several places, so I thought why not in a class singleton I created with some app wide data. I declare it as a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *toolbarItems;
```

Then I initialized it in that class' init method:

```
_toolbarItems = @[           
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(menuOne)],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(menuTwo)]
];
```

For each view controller's viewDidLoad method I set the toolbarItems property:

```
self.toolbarItems = [MySingleton shared].toolbarItems;
```

The toolbar items appear on initial presentation of view controller one. It also appears when presenting view controller two, but when I switch back to view controller one, the tool bar items are no longer present. The toolbaritems property still says it has two items in it, though. My guess is the UIBarButtonItem themselves have somehow been deallocated, but I don't know why.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger/`NSLog` statements to try to identify where they might be getting deallocated?

Comment: I added an NSLog(@"count = %li", [self.toolbarItems count]) in viewWillAppear:, but it still reports that it has two items, even though none appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Singleton object is being retained, but not the array itself in the Singleton object.

The array object itself that you created using `@[]` autoreleases, but does not get retained, and you assign it directly to the instance variable by using `_toolbarItems`. I think you need to do `self.toolbarItems = @[`...

Comment: I was actually hopeful this would work and sparked some old memories about retain, but it didn't. This might mean the problem lies elsewhere. There are still a tiny bit difference in my sample which I will add when I have time.